# For trillions of years, quietly I sat

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Just thought of this one, might be pretty easy, but I think it should be challenging enough.

> For trillions of years, quietly I sat.
>
> Well, I wasn't quiet at all, but it sure seemed like that.
>
> For I work in the background, doing my part,
>
> If I were not there, it would all fall apart
>
> I am appreciated by all, and understoood by some.
>
> With my prefix lies the power of the people; with my suffix their home
>
> Take care not to touch me, for I might make you fly
>
> Now tell me, if you can: What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Electricity?

For trillions of years, quietly I sat.

> Until Ben Franklin discovered it.

Well, I wasn't quiet at all, but it sure seemed like that.

> lightning but no light bulbs

For I work in the background, doing my part,

> On my computer and my house lights.

If I were not there, it would all fall apart

> No electricity = no power =  no electronics

I am appreciated by all, and understoood by some.

> I love it,engineers and electician understand it.

With my prefix lies the power of the people; with my suffix their home

> Electric and City

Take care not to touch me, for I might make you fly

> Zap.

Comment: Darn it, now that I see this answer, it seems obvious and much better compared to mine.

Comment: I still think your answer it pretty good :) +1

Comment: Curse you @QuantumTwinkie

Comment: Stop being good at this

Comment: You win this round, but I will not rest until I have stumped you.....

Comment: I will note though, that it was not edison who discovered it. There are records of primitive batteries dating thousands of years back, and certainly Ben Franklin and his kite were before edison

Comment: Hahaha, yeah fixed :)

Comment: @Cubemaster, that's actually a misconception. There are no records that indicate that electricity has been around for thousands of years (mythbusters actually has an episode on it). Not to mention that Ben Franklin didn't discover electricity, he just found the connection between lightning and electricity.

Comment: So far as we know, the universe is only about 14 billion years old.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Gravity?

For trillions of years, quietly I sat.
Well, I wasn't quiet at all, but it sure seemed like that.

> Gravity has been present forever, and it's hardly noticeable. But it truly is loud (like glacial movements).

If I were not there, it would all fall apart

> Without gravity, nothing would exist.

I am appreciated by all, and understoood by some.

> Everyone knows without gravity, we wouldn't have much. It's understood by very few. In fact, you could argue that we don't understand gravity at all.

With my prefix lies the power of the people; with my suffix their home

> Not sure

Take care not to touch me, for I might make you fly

> If you mess with gravity, you could end up floating or flying.

Comment: Not quite. You are on the right track, but that second to last line is important